# How can I reach second child in Android firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to reach second child directly , first child name is random.

I want to reach kullaniciadi child;

https://i.hizliresim.com/dO58mp.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 DatabaseReference db=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Kullanicilar");
 db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
               String kullaniciad=data.child("kullaniciadi").getValue().toString();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Here you have the datasnapshot at child `Kullanicilar`. Then you iterate inside of it and get the child `kullaniciadi` that is under the pushids

Comment: Thanks for answer , can you see again my post? , I edited.

Comment: what is this query `kullanicilarDatabaseRef`?